# Get previous URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, xmlhttprequest

I am looking for a solution with javascript to check if the previous page is not extranal.

With this check I want return true or false so I can use this for another function.

What I have tried is to get the previous URL with `history.go(-1)` but this is undefined.

I am happy if I can get the previous URL so far.

Hope somebody can help me out with this.

Comment: In JS it's `document.referrer`.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply use** to know previous URL

```js
document.referrer
```

```js
 document.write(document.referrer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) to get the URL of the previous page.

To check whether it is external or not, you can parse it with the [`URL` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and compare its origin.

```js
const previousURL = document.referrer;

const isPreviousURLExternal = new URL(previousURL).origin == new URL(location).origin;
console.log(isPreviousURLExternal)
```